Initial Functors (Elementarily)
Given a functor $F \colon \mathcal{C} \longrightarrow \mathcal{D}$, a limit of $F$ is a cone $(L, (p_D)_{D \in \mathcal{D}})$ on $F$ such that for any cone $(M, (q_D)_{D \in \mathcal{D}})$ on $F$, there exists a unique morphism $m \colon M \longrightarrow L$ such that for every object $D \in \mathcal{D},\ q_{D} = p_D \circ m$.
Defn. (Initial Functor) A functor $F \colon \mathcal{C} \longrightarrow \mathcal{D}$ is intial if for any set valued functor $G \colon \mathcal{D} \longrightarrow \textbf{Set}$, the limit of $G$ is the same as the limit of $G \circ F$.
From
Prop 3.1 (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/final+functor). I have attemped to prove some equivalence conditions BUT Note: I have replaced final with initial and colimits with limits.
I tried to prove 1, 4,5,6
Proof
$(1) \implies  (4)$: Suppose $(L, (p_D)_{D \in \mathcal{D}})$ is the limit of $G$, then $(L, (p_{FC})_{C \in \mathcal{C}})$ is the limit of $G \circ F$.
$(4) \implies (5)$: It suffices to show that if $\lim_{\leftarrow} G \circ F$ exists then $\lim_{\leftarrow} G$ exists as well. If $(L, (q_C)_{C \in \mathcal{C}})$ is the limit of $G \circ F$, then we can express the limit of $G$ as $(L, (p_D)_{D \in \mathcal{D}})$ with $p_{FC} = q_C$.
Is this proof correct? and how do I link this with $(6)$ and $(7)$ for initial functors.
